# Winforms: Prevent Automatic Drawing of Child Controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, gdi+

I'm working on creating a Control/UserControl that is capable of Panning, Zooming, and displaying items based upon Cartesian Coordinates. I actually have these features working for internal test images.

I'd like to treat this as a general, re-usable panel where I can add standard Controls/UserControls and have them be drawn with respects to the panning and zooming.

In the paint method I can call a Controls DrawToBitmap function to partially accomplish this. However, this ends up drawing the child controls twice: once in the panel's OnPaint method like I want, and one additional time from somewhere else in the framework. And, with this framework invocation, the padding, zooming, and Cartesian coordinates are ignored.

Is there a standard way that I can take control of the painting process of a UserControl so that I can prevent child controls from drawing themselves? Or, alternatively, apply scaling and transforms to the Graphics object getting passed along to the children to achieve the same effect?

Thanks

Comment: I found one work-around, though not ideal. Setting the child control's Visibility to false will prevent the framework from drawing it. However, then I have no *standard* way to determine if a control should or should not be drawn.

Comment: What is the use of these controls? When painted, they won't do much. Do you actually need them, or you just want to paint them? You can just keep them off-screen. Maybe, provide some more context to your scenario.

Comment: The immediate application is for interactive processing of scientific data in a graphic format. I'll want to include annotations and such. I can do this without being able to support standard controls - perhaps using non-graphical Components or the like instead. However, it would be nice to generically extend support for all standard controls if possible. Of course, things like mouse and keyboard events would have to get re-routed for full support.

Comment: The general application functionality may be interesting but it's not related to your current question. You should explai what you're trying to achieve in more details. Add some Images of the desired/current results if you think it will make it easier to understand.

Comment: The generalized functionality is the question at hand. I know how to achieve the immediate application features for completely custom classes.

Comment: Found a better tenative solution. I create an invisible form to host the controls. Enable scrolling on the invisible form and allow the ViewControl to control the scroll bar positions and such. The ViewControl can then request that the form DrawToBitmap. Tenatively appears to work, although I'll need to figure out how to then translate events from the View to the invisible form. This won't allow for Cartesian Coordinates, but I can work around that separately.

Comment: Nope take it back - doesn't work well. The form has to be visible or the internal controls don't render, which defeats the purpose >.>

Comment: The WPF toolkit, in particular the VisualTarget class, may be better suited to this sort of arbitrary transformation of controls. Winforms wasn't really designed for this.

Comment: @VincentPovirk Yes WPF would probably have what I need. Unfortunately I don't get to select the technologies for this project :(